# Markdown: is possible to merge a features page with a keypoints?

Tags: yaml, grav

I'm building a one page template with markdown. I have something like this in the Markdown:

```
title: Services
menu: Services
class: small
features:
-
    header: Rechenzentrum
    image: icon1.png
-
    header: Kollaboration
    image: icon2.png    
-
    header: Archiv
    image: icon3.png
-
    header: Wertsachen
    image: icon4.png
```

What i need is to merge another section with some "kaypoints".
Is this possible?

Comment: That's not Markdown. It looks like YAML?

Comment: I'm using Grav CMS that uses markdown and yaml, yes.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? do you want to include some part of another page? or do you want to merge two pages together? Either way maybe you can get away with modulars pages or manual include like `{{ page.find('/some/other.page').content }}`.